How to log from an ILogger
I have created an ILogger which logs some messages, based on EventId, by sending an Email.
Sending the email might fail and I want to log that.
(I will ensure it doesn't create a loop)
Injecting an ILogger or ILoggerFactory into the provider or any of its' dependecies will cause a circular reference.
public class EmailLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider 
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public EmailLoggerProvider(ILogger<EmailLoggerProvider logger) // doesn't work
    {
    }

    ...
        _logger.LogError(...);
}

Currently I inject the IServiceProvider instead and create the logger when needed.
public class EmailLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider 
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _service;

    public EmailLoggerProvider(IServiceProvider service) 
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    ...
        _service.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EmailLoggerProvider>>().LogError(...);
}

Is there a better way so I can avoid taking a dependency on the DI framework. Was thinking about Func<ILogger<EmailLoggerProvider>> which should work but makes the normal case require an extra service registration services.AddSingleton(s => s.GetRequiredService<ILogger<EmailLoggerProvider>>())
Lazy<ILogger<EmailLoggerProvider>> could work but also requires an extra service registration.

Hi @adrianm,  You can avoid depending on the DI framework is to inject ILoggerFactory instead of ILogger. You can create the logger on demand without triggering a circular reference:

@Rena, injecting a ILoggerFactory causes the same circular reference. I assume the LoggerFactory is a singleton which adds all registered providers on first instance.
